# How to save files on android storage, write to them, and access them later on?

Tags: java, android, arrays, file, text-files

I am working on an android app to take float values from 3 different arrays, transform them into strings and then store them into a text file on the internal storage of the phone. I want to be able to access these values later and put them on a computer so I can do some statistical analysis on them. Can someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 0):

Create a File object, and store your values in a flat-file database. For more info on how to create a flat-file database, go [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17984_01/doc.898/e14711/flat_files.htm). To learn more about the File API, go [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_file_class.htm). To learn about more data storage options that Android provides, go [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).